# Does react native component remount on orientation?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile-application

I am just new to react native and want to know whether the component remounts on the change in orientation of the device.  Because I think its not happening in my case.

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on your activity configuration. You can test is by adding a log to componentDidMount function to see when it is mounted

```
componentDidMount(){
 console.warn("did mount!")
}
```